# Initializing only one member in a C struct for an array of struct elements

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I have the following code with an intention to initialize member b. This should happen for all the MAX_SIZE structs.

```
enum { MAX_SIZE = 10 };

struct some
{
    int a, b;
}
many[MAX_SIZE] = { {.b = 5} };

int main() 
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, %d\n", many[i].a, many[i].b);
    }
}
```

I need the output to look like:

```
0, 5
0, 5
0, 5
... (10 times)
```

But, the actual output is:

```
0, 5
0, 0
0, 0
... (10 times)
```

How to get the required output without requiring an explicit for loop for assigning the values? I know in C++, this is accomplished by providing a constructor for the struct initializing b only.

Comment: GCC has an extension to do this; Standard C does not support it other than by writing the initializer out many times.  Also note that the members not explicitly initialized are zero-initialized. (It’s annoying too. Fortran IV, aka Fortran 66, allowed repeats of initializers.)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/51241230/15168

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not C Standard, but with this [gcc extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) you can do this :

```
struct some many[10] = { [0 ... 9].b = 5 };
```

It works with *`clang >= 5`* too.

Comment: @mch Yes it works, but it will iterate from 0 to `MAX_SIZE` included. One other way to do that is to `#define MAX_SIZE 9` and to declare array like :
`struct some many[] = {0 ... MAX_SIZE].b = value };`. This will declare an array of size `MAX_SIZE + 1`.

Comment: I am using clang-900.0.39.2, but it gave me the following error. `struct.c:10:33: error: array designator cannot initialize non-array type
      'struct some'
struct some many[MAX_SIZE] = { {[0 ... MAX_SIZE].b = 5} };`
The carat character (^) was pointing at the opening square bracket to the left of zero (0).

Comment: @Seshadri Maybe you put too much braces and as I said before, you can't use `MAX_SIZE` like that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the howler. Removing the extra pair of braces got the compiler produce the desired result.